# Create Resume problem

Tags: c#

i am working on a project of online resume management system and i am encountering an exception while creating resume.
[b]
Exception: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. [/b]

here is my code for Create Resume-1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string sql, sql2, sql3, sql4, sql5, sql6, sql7, sql8, sql9, sql10, sql11, sql12;
    string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\\Deliverable4.accdb";
    protected OleDbConnection rMSConnection;
    protected OleDbCommand rMSCommand;
    protected OleDbDataAdapter rMSDataAdapter;
    protected DataSet dataSet;
    protected DataTable dataTable;
    protected DataRow dataRow;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string contact1 = TextBox1.Text;
        string contact2 = TextBox2.Text;
        string cellphone = TextBox3.Text;
        string address = TextBox4.Text;
        string city = TextBox5.Text;
        string addqualification = TextBox18.Text;
        //string SecondLastDegreeGrade = TextBox17.Text;
        //string SecondLastDegreeInstitute = TextBox16.Text;
        //string SecondLastDegreeNameOther = TextBox15.Text;
        string LastDegreeNameOther = TextBox11.Text;
        string LastDegreeInstitute = TextBox12.Text;
        string LastDegreeGrade = TextBox13.Text;
        string tentativeFromDate = (DropDownList4.SelectedValue + " " + DropDownList7.SelectedValue + " " + DropDownList8.SelectedValue);
        try
        {
            sql6 = "select CountryID from COUNTRY";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql6, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("cID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "COUNTRY");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["COUNTRY"];

            int cId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql4 = "select PersonalDetailID from PERSONALDETAIL";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql4, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("PDID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "PERSONALDETAIL");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["PERSONALDETAIL"];

            int PDId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql5 = "update PERSONALDETAIL set Phone1 ='" + contact1 + "' , Phone2 = '" + contact2 + "', CellPhone = '" + cellphone + "', Address = '" + address + "', City = '" + city + "', CountryID = '" + cId + "' where PersonalDetailID = '" + PDId + "'";            
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSConnection.Open();
            rMSCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql5, rMSConnection);
            rMSCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql3 = "select DesignationID from DESIGNATION";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql3, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("DesID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "DESIGNATION");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["DESIGNATION"];

            int desId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql2 = "select DepartmentID from DEPARTMENT";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("DID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "DEPARTMENT");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["DEPARTMENT"];

            int dId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql7 = "select ResumeID from RESUME";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql7, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("rID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "RESUME");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["RESUME"];

            int rId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql = "update RESUME set PersonalDetailID ='" + PDId + "' , DesignationID = '" + desId + "', DepartmentID = '" + dId + "', TentativeFromDate = '" + tentativeFromDate + "', AdditionalQualification = '" + addqualification + "' where ResumeID = '" + rId + "'";

            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSConnection.Open();
            rMSCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, rMSConnection);
            rMSCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql8 = "insert into INSTITUTE (InstituteName) values ('" + LastDegreeInstitute + "')";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSConnection.Open();
            rMSCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql8, rMSConnection);
            rMSCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql9 = "insert into DEGREE (DegreeName) values ('" + LastDegreeNameOther + "')";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSConnection.Open();
            rMSCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql9, rMSConnection);
            rMSCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql11 = "select InstituteID from INSTITUTE";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql11, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("insID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "INSTITUTE");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["INSTITUTE"];

            int insId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql12 = "select DegreeID from DEGREE";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql12, rMSConnection);
            dataSet = new DataSet("degID");
            rMSDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "DEGREE");

            dataTable = dataSet.Tables["DEGREE"];

            int degId = (int)dataTable.Rows[0][0];

            rMSConnection.Close();

            sql10 = "insert into QUALIFICATION (Grade, ResumeID, InstituteID, DegreeID) values ('" + LastDegreeGrade + "', '" + rId + "', '" + insId + "', '" + degId + "')";
            rMSConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            rMSConnection.Open();
            rMSCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql10, rMSConnection);
            rMSCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            rMSConnection.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Applicant.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            rMSConnection.Close();
            Label1.Text = "Exception: " + exp.Message;
        }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

And for Create Resume-1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Create Resume-1.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><center>
        <strong><span style="font-size: 16pt"></span></strong>&nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <strong><span style="font-size: 16pt">Step 1</span></strong></center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
        <asp:Label ID="PhoneNo1" runat="server" Text="Contact No 1*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="PhoneNo2" runat="server" Text="Contact No 2"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="CellNo" runat="server" Text="Cell Phone No"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Address" runat="server" Text="Street Address*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox4"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="City" runat="server" Text="City*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox5"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Country" runat="server" Text="Country of Origin*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryID">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [COUNTRY] WHERE (([CountryID] = ?) OR ([CountryID] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [COUNTRY] ([CountryID], [CountryName]) VALUES (?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [COUNTRY]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [COUNTRY] SET [CountryName] = ? WHERE (([CountryID] = ?) OR ([CountryID] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountryName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CountryName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="DepartmentOfInterest" runat="server" Text="Department of Interest*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="DepartmentName" DataValueField="DepartmentID">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DEPARTMENT] WHERE [DepartmentID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DEPARTMENT] ([DepartmentID], [DepartmentName]) VALUES (?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DEPARTMENT]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DEPARTMENT] SET [DepartmentName] = ? WHERE [DepartmentID] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DepartmentName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="DesignationAppliedFor" runat="server" Text="Position Applied For*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="DesignationName" DataValueField="DesignationID">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DESIGNATION] WHERE [DesignationID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DESIGNATION] ([DesignationID], [DesignationName], [DesignationStatus]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DESIGNATION]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DESIGNATION] SET [DesignationName] = ?, [DesignationStatus] = ? WHERE [DesignationID] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationStatus" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DesignationStatus" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList3"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="TentativeFromDate" runat="server" Text="Can Join From*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList4"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></center>
        <center>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LastDegreeName" runat="server" Text="Last Degree*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" DataTextField="DegreeName" DataValueField="DegreeID">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource5" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DEGREE] WHERE [DegreeID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DEGREE] ([DegreeID], [DegreeName]) VALUES (?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DEGREE]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DEGREE] SET [DegreeName] = ? WHERE [DegreeID] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList5"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="LastDegreeNameOther" runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="LastDegreeInstitute" runat="server" Text="Institute Name*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox12"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="LastDegreeGrade" runat="server" Text="Marks / Grade*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox13"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="SecondLastDegreeName" runat="server" Text="Second Last Degree*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="DegreeName" DataValueField="DegreeID">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7 %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DEGREE] WHERE [DegreeID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DEGREE] ([DegreeID], [DegreeName]) VALUES (?, ?)"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString7.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DEGREE]"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DEGREE] SET [DegreeName] = ? WHERE [DegreeID] = ?">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DegreeName" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="DropDownList6"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="SecondLastDegreeNameOther" runat="server" Text="Other"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="SecondLastDegreeInstitute" runat="server" Text="Institute Name*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox16"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
        <asp:Label ID="SecondLastDegreeGrade" runat="server" Text="Marks / Grade*"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Items marked with '*' cannot be left blank." ControlToValidate="TextBox17"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></center>
        <center>
            <br />
        <asp:Label ID="AdditionalQualification" runat="server" Text="Additional Qualification"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save and Exit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Button2_Click" /></center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whic line does the exception throw on?

Comment: Remove the `try-catch` in your event handler. Then you will get an error message which includes a full stacktrace. This stacktrace will help you find the problematic line in your code. If you still cannot find the error, append the stacktrace to your question here.

Comment: PS: This has nothing to do with your question, but have a look at the `using` statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx You should use this instead of manually closing your OleDbConnections. This will also ensure that "the right thing" is done automatically in the case of exceptions.

Comment: As an aside, supposing contact1 was is entered as "x'; DROP TABLE PERSONALDETAIL; --"? Bang goes your data... all of it. If you don't understand SQL injection, take a read of this page: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html and start thinking about parameterized queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates an issue with one of the SQL statements you are creating.  If you remove the `catch` block, and but in a `finally` block to close the connection, you should be able to see which statement is causing the exception.  My best guess is a formatting problem with one of your dates.

Also, you should really consider using parameterized queries.  This has SQL Injection Attack written all over it.

Comment: +1 for parameterized queries.  See my all-time favorite IT comic: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_isk1o8_XWYA/R0ML6q6-HYI/AAAAAAAAAtY/_bm0dffd6Gc/s1600-h/exploits_of_a_mom.png